# Multiple sessions or one?

Tags: php, forms, session

I am using a security token for a form, the form is dynamically built depending on selection through jquery. So the form is called quite a lot and different tokens created every-time.

So.. if the same user calls the form 3 times the session would be rewritten?
Would it help at all to check if the token exists and not create one unless its empty?
or perhaps someone knows of a good way to work with form tokens?

If 3 users are on then the token is created 3 times with different values, right?
If I check for the token and 3 users are on then the session is created 3 times with the same values?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you plan to do with the tokens? Will the same selected responses from the form generate the same token for all users? Are you trying to emulate CSRF token functionality? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention

Comment: Yes, my question is since the form is called from jquery, is it ok that the token is generated everytime someone clicks the form button?

Comment: What do you plan to do with said token?

Comment: its just checked at the server for security, i have 2 options, have one token that lasts 15 min or create new one everytime someone clicks.

Comment: I would suggest you follow Norse's suggestion and simply create a new, random token every-time the page is submitted, regardless of the selections made by a user. I still think you are trying to emulate CSRF tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new token each time the page is loaded. Don't check if the token exists already, just generate a new one each time. This won't duplicate tokens; there will always be one per user, but unique for each time the page is loaded.

The above will decrease the chance that users will haven the same token, although if you're generating a unique string via `md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));` then you don't have to worry about duplicate token ids (it's possible, but really you'd have a better chance at being the one person picked out of the entire Earth population)